# Possible typo in my textbook

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I'm working through my probability textbook, and I think that the following is a typo, but I'm not sure. I'm asking because this result is quite important.

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be identically distributed random variables with common moment generating function $M$. Let $N$ be a random variable taking non-negative integer values with probability generating function $G$, and suppose $N$ is independent of the sequence $(X_i)$. Show that the random sum $S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$ has moment generating function $M_S(t)=G(M(t))$.

I can prove this if $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, and I think the statement is not (necessarily) true if they are dependent. Am I right and is this a typo, or is the statement also true if  $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are possibly dependent? And if so, why? Because for the case of a random sum of discrete random variables we need independence, according to my textbook. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If say $X_1=X_2=\cdots$, the conclusion is obviously false.

Comment: Because in general $\mathbb{E}(e^{NtX})\neq(\mathbb{E}(e^{tX}))^N$, right?

Comment: As a general bit of advice, you believe that there is a typographical error in a text, searching the book's author, title, and the word "errata" on Google often brings up a list of mistakes that have been spotted and fixed.  Also, if you find a legitimate typo, it is not unreasonable to send a **polite** email to the author to let them know of the error.

Comment: I tried that already and the textbook contains many typos. There is document but that one only considers the first 100 pages and I found more typos than the ones in the document already.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: of course I though about the case that the whole sequence is equal, i.e. $X_1=X_2= \cdots$, but is it really so obvious that the statement is false then? I'm a bit in doubt.

Comment: It appears they omitted a hypothesis of independence that should have been there.

Comment: My guess is you can prove, from $M_S(t)=G_N(M(t))$ for all non-negative integer valued r.v.s, that the $X_i$ must be independent, by examining mixed moments of the $X_i$.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think it's clear now and it should also not be difficult to find a counterexample for dependent variables for which the statement does not apply.

Comment: If $N=2$ a.s., and $X_1=X_2\sim N(0,1)$ then $M(t)=\exp(t^2/2)$ and $M_S(t) = \exp(2t^2)$ but $G(M(t))=\exp(t^2)$.